# import react component from another folder

Tags: reactjs

i have a folder component .

There is OutlinedField in component  folder.

in App.js  i do `import OutlinedField from "./../component";` but it fails.

My code is at https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-cloud-ngk6u?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have `component` folder in same directory as `app.js` file, you only need to add 
`import OutlinedField from './component/OutlinedField'`

### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import OutlinedField from './component/OutlinedField';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: that works..but how do i use that imported component https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-sanderson-ngzkr

Comment: Add this < OutlinedField /> Before closing tag of div